# Cannot Deploy to AVAX C-Chain Mainnet | Internal JSON-RPC error. { “code”: -32000, “message”: “execution reverted” }

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix, erc20

I've been trying to deploy a smart contract to the AVAX C-Chain Mainnet but continue to get this error:

Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" }

The code snippet that seems to be giving me an issue is this:

```
IDEXRouter public router; //The DEX router
address public pair; //The address for the token pair
address public WAVAX = 0xB31f66AA3C1e785363F0875A1B74E27b85FD66c7; //Avalanche WAVAX
router = IDEXRouter(_router); //Initialize the router with the TraderJoeV2 router address
pair = IDEXFactory(router.factory()).createPair(WAVAX, address(this)); //Update the pair address
```

_router represents the TraderJoeV2 AVAX C-Chain Mainnet Address, which is 0x60aE616a2155Ee3d9A68541Ba4544862310933d4

I know the most common resolution to this problem seems to be the router address needing to be changed, but the address is correct for the Avalanche C-Chain Mainnet.

I've actually deployed the same exact contract on BSC (Mainnet and Testnet) and ETH (Mainnet and Rinkeby Testnet) with the respective PancakeSwap/Uniswap router addresses and it works perfectly fine. This issue only seems to happen when attempting to deploy to AVAX. I'm using Remix and have no issues with compiling the code.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated, as I'm completely stuck as to why it works on other networks but not AVAX.

Thank you!

Comment: where you able to resolve this issue? I have the same!